# Solr query to return phrase without using shingle field

Tags: solr, nosql, facet, autosuggest, shingles

I have a solr index that contains a text field with approximately 1000 words per document.
i want to do a query or facet that will return only part of the text field.
for example:

```
text_field = ["this is the important question from this site"]
```

and i want to make a query that will return only the "important question" out of the "important" search.
this is because some of the text fields contain other "coupling" to the word important and i want to get them also.

i know about the shingle usage but i don't want to "pay" the disk cost on indexing part of the text.

Comment: [Highlighting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/highlighting.html)?

Comment: How, we tried to do it

Comment: What did you try? What is the type of your fields? What content is indexed? What is your query? What did you get back that didn't fit with what you wanted? Expand your question